# How to switch from foreground application to background agent?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, background-agents

I'd like to know if it is possible to switch from foreground app to background agent and vice-versa sharing some data from these two tasks?

More in deep I'd like to do an **upload** that starts from foreground (Fig. A) and when the user pushes back button the upload continues with background agent (Fig. B).

Image is here: http://imageshack.us/f/823/testter.jpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Background file transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202955%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is what you need. It can upload (and download) files while the application is not running:

> With Windows Phone OS 7.1, applications are able to queue up one or
>   more file uploads or downloads over HTTP that will be executed in the
>   background, even when the application is no longer running in the
>   foreground. The APIs used for initiating file transfers should be used
>   to query the status existing transfers and provide progress indicators
>   for the end user.

Comment: I'm bit confused... I'd like upload an image on twitter from background agent so isn't possible? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You do realize that you can't update the tile constantly from a PeriodicTask right? The minimum refresh time is 30 minutes, unless you do push notifications (which I here, assume you won't, since it's a client-side operation).

And the tile itself doesn't make much sense. And I don't think using a task that can maximum run for 25 seconds makes a aweful lot of sense either for uploading a file.

So I guess we can conclude that it'll not be possible to do this. Instead , you should allow the application to run in the background, by setting the `ApplicationIdleDetectionMode` to `Disabled`

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetecetionMode.Diabled"
```

Then the user can press the Home button, and the download will progress in the background.

Comment: The backgound task can inform the server side which will issue a push notification =)

Comment: There's many crazy ways to do it, if you *really* wanted to. I wouldn't recommend any of them :p

Comment: yes I read background file transfer but it's clearly in contrast with the "rules" of periodicTask... the problem is that background transfer isn't explained very well and there's no much examples :)